# I can't get environment variables using CMake in Windows 10

Tags: boost, cmake

I added THIRD_PARTY environment variable in Windows 10

[image]

and I tried using $ENV in CMake to load the path.

But, it failed. When checked using the CMake message function, nothing is output.

I checked the environment variable path once more.

I don't know what my problem is. Please help me.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you closed and reopened your console or Visual Studio window after adding the environment variable? The environment is only passed to a program at startup. Later changes to the environment are not propagated to running programs.

Comment: omg..., It is working. You were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close and reopen your console or Visual Studio window after adding or changing the environment variable.

The environment is only passed to a program at startup. Later changes to the environment are not propagated to running programs.